# python3 use google-app-engine receive email, how to configure to specific app, not default app

Tags: python, email, google-app-engine

I am able to receive eamil at the default service of google-app-engine, the address is anystring@my-appid.appspotmail.com, but I need to send to a specific service, not the default service, how can I do that, below is my code, thanks in advance.

### app.yaml

```
runtime: python39 
app_engine_apis: true 
service: target-service
inbound_services: 
- mail 
- mail_bounce
```

handle code:main.py

```
from flask import Flask, request
from google.appengine.api import wrap_wsgi_app
from google.appengine.api import mail
app = Flask(__name__)
app.wsgi_app = wrap_wsgi_app(app.wsgi_app, use_deferred=True)
@app.route('/_ah/mail/<path>', methods=['POST'])
def receive_mail(path):
    mail_message = mail.InboundEmailMessage(request.get_data())
    print("called")
    return 'Success'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tested this in Python2.7 but I believe it should work in Python3 (the principle should be the same when it comes to the mail part but might require a few tweaks for the other places)

1. I have a `default` service with an `app.yaml` file and another service called `second-service` with `second-service.yaml`.
2. Added the following to both `app.yaml` & `second-service.yaml` files

```
    inbound_services:
        - mail
```

3. Added this to `second-service.yaml` Note that my python file here is called `second.py`. It handles traffic routed to `second-service`

```
- url: /_ah/mail/.+
  script: second.app
```

4. Added this to `app.yaml` Note that my python file here is called ``main.py```.

```
- url: /_ah/mail/.+
  script: main.app
```

5. Added the following to both `main.py` and `second.py`

```
@app.route('/_ah/mail/<path>', methods=['POST'])
def receive_mail(path):
    mail_message = mail.InboundEmailMessage(request.get_data())
    logging.info(mail_message.subject)
    return 'Success'
```

6. For testing, I sent emails to the addresses below and they were only received by their respective services.

Note: I used `-dot-` and not `.` for the multi-service bit.

a) support@second-service-dot-<project_id>.appspotmail.com

b) support@<project_id>.appspotmail.com

Final bit: I only have `service: second-service` within `second-service.yaml`

Comment: looking for this answer for ages, It work brilliant, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use a specific service in App Engine, you need to specify it in the [`app.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#service):

```
service: service-name
```

Additionally if you are planning to use multiple services in your app, here's a [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/configuration-files) you can use to structure your app.

Comment: thanks Mabel, after I added service: my-service to yaml, I found the anystring@my-appid.appspotmail.com still put to my default service, I think I need to to update the email address? something like anystring@my-appid.mytergetservice.appspotmail.com? but I have tried this, but not work

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/dispatcher.py?r=411#704
I also found this link, url with _ah is not be able to dispatch

Comment: @alextre did you update the `<path>` in your `main.py`? It should be your email address as mentioned in this [article](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/services/mail#using_the_mail_api).

Comment: @ Mabel A, now the problem is email post for anystring@my-appid.appspotmail.com, always go to default service, so the main,py service instance never ha chance get called, and my goal is to make the mail post go to specific service, rather than the default service

Comment: @alextre have you checked NoCommandLine's answer? That's the proper way to structure your app for using other services aside from the default as stated on the second link I provided in my answer.